# Environment-dependent compilation properties in Flex/AIR

Tags: apache-flex, properties, air, flash-builder

I'm building a Flex/AIR application that connects to a remote server, the URL of which changes depending on the environment (development/production, and possibly others). For now, this URL parameter is hardcoded in my root application MXML file but it means I have to change it everytime I build my app for a different environment.

Is there a way to externalize such a parameter so that when Flash Builder automatically builds my app (in development mode), it uses the development URL (http://localhost...) and when Flash Builder exports a release build, it uses the production URL (http://www.mycompany.com/myapp)?

Answer (score 0):

Flex compiler supports something called Conditional compilation, you an read about it here: [link](http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/conditionalcompilation.pdf). The problem is that it still doesn't give you an way to check if you're exporting a release build or building for debug. Probably the simplest way to achieve that is to use ANT for compilation of the release build and use the conditional compilation from there.